# Is there any good tutorial on how to read, convert and process .spc files using Python, R, Ruby, Java?

Tags: resource-recommendations, software, raman-spectroscopy

Is there any good tutorial on how to read, convert and process .spc files using Python, R, Ruby, Java?  Need to extract content of 30 .spc vibrational spectroscopy files to do PCA and descriptive statistics.

Comment: Related by OP: [What are the good software to convert vibrational spectroscopy .spc files into .csv or .tab?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366520/what-are-the-good-software-to-convert-vibrational-spectroscopy-spc-files-into)

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used it myself, you could try [this here example notebook](https://github.com/rohanisaac/spc/blob/master/notebooks/spc_test.ipynb) of a spc package for Python. It seems to work with numpy, so plugging PCA into that via scikit-learn should be easy.